# File upload working on localhost but not working after publishing on server

Tags: php, mysql

Actually My problem is when I am registering user profile on localhost is working fine and image is storing in folder but after published is not storing image in folder.

my php code

```
  $target_dir = "../upload/";
        $target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["photo"]["name"]);

        $uploadOk = 1;
        if ($uploadOk == 0) {
            echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
           } else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], $target_file); 

        }

        $name = $_POST["name"];

        $email = $_POST["email"];

        $sql = "SELECT email FROM register where email='$email'";
        $qur = $connection->query($sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($qur)==0)
        {

        $password = md5($_POST["password"]);
        $birth = $_POST["birth"];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO register(name, email,password,photo,birth)
         VALUES ('$name','$email','$password','$target_file','$birth')";
        $success = $connection->query($sql);

        if (!$success) {
            die("Couldn't enter data: ".$connection->error);

        }else{
         echo "Thank You For registration";

         }
   }else{echo "Email-id already exist";
}
```

Comment: add permission? check the path ?

Comment: use getcwd() to get current working directory and make sure ../upload is actually where you want the image placed

Comment: after registration it is showing "500 - Internal server error."

Comment: When I am using localhost its working fine, But after deployed on server then It is not working (Image is not storing in upload folder). In database image path is showing like: ../upload/mypic.jpg. But there is no any mypic image in upload folder.

Answer (score 1):

most of the time server need dont allow to upload data.

you need to give permission to your upload folder and it will work

Answer (score 0):

You can check your error: `$_FILES['photo']['error']`

You can get more detail from here :- http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php